# Variance(XY + X/Y)

Tags: statistics, variance

Suppose X has a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance s^2. Let Y be an independent random variable taking values 1 and -1 with equal probability. Define Z= XY + X/Y. Which of the following is true?

(a) Var(Z) > s^2

(b) Var(Z) < s^2

(c) Var(Z) = s^2

(d) Var(Z) can be greater than or smaller than s^2

Variance of Y would be 1 and Var(Z) = Var(XY) + Var(X/Y) + 2 covariance(XY,X/Y). Can anyone suggest how to proceed further. Should I consider X and Y independent and then calculate?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Might help to note that $\frac 1Y=Y$.

Comment: Can you explain why? They will have the same means and variance but why equal?

Comment: At each observation we have $Y=\pm 1$.  In each case, $Y=\frac 1Y$.

Comment: $Z$ has the same distribution as $2X$

Comment: Did you get it ?

Comment: Yes, got the answer : 4s^2. Thanks!